# Want to overwrite specific character on a specific line in a text file with new characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I Have a program that calculates a score 'LevelScore' and i want to open the UserFile 'UserScoreFile' and check against the current user score saved in the file, and if LevelScore > CurrentScore overwrite the previous characters representing that levels score in the text file to the LevelScore.

Each line in the Text file represents a level from 0-7 with each line format being, "T 000", T is representing if level is unlocked and 000 represents the current score (score can be 0-100) "lev" is a variable from 0-7 indicating which level the user is on.

```
UserFileR = open("UserScoreFile.txt","r")
    UserFileLines = UserFileR.readlines()
    UserLevelLine = UserFileLines[lev]
    UserLevelScore = UserLevelLine[2:5]

 if LevelScore > UserLevelScore:
    UserFileWR = open("UserScoreFile.txt","r+")
    #This is where i dont know what to do...
```

Comment: Hi Luke! Welcome to the dark side... Why aren't you in lesson >:(

Comment: The [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) does this transparently. But are you sure you want to open, read, change and write back the entire file every time a score changes? Wouldn't it be better to read the file into a list when your program starts, track changes in-memory and write back that list to a file upon exit?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I know Luke in real life and have helped him with his project, he does need to change contents of a file multiple times during the execution of his program. (he's making a touch-typing program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution me and Luke have come up with collaboratively:

```
UserFileRW = open("UserScoreFile.txt","r+")
UserFileLines = UserFileRW.readlines()
UserLevelLine = UserFileLines[lev]
UserLevelScore = int(UserLevelLine[2:])
UserFileRW.close()

if LevelScore > UserLevelScore:
    UserFileWR = open("UserScoreFile.txt","w+")
    UserFileLines[lev] = "T " + str(LevelScore) + "\n"
    UserFileRW.writelines(UserFileLines)
    UserFileRW.close()
```

Thank you to Jotto and Tim Pietzcker for your contributions.

Comment: Good for you. I forgot that opening with `w+` will remove if it exists. As well as writelines adds `\n` at the and of list's element.

Comment: @jotto We based it on your original solution after some debugging, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started.

```
UserFileRW = open("UserScoreFile.txt","r+")
UserFileLines = UserFileR.readlines()
UserLevelLine = UserFileLines[lev]
UserLevelScore = int(UserLevelLine[2:5])

if int(LevelScore) > UserLevelScore:
    UserFileRW.truncate()
    UserFileLines[lev] = "some tex" + str(LevelScore)  # there is something before score, but I don't know what
    UserFileRW.write(''.join(UserFileLines))
    UserFileRW.close()
```

Unfortunately this is not possible to change something in the middle of file. So you have to parse all of it, make modifications and then write it again.

Comment: Commenting on Luke Gibson's behalf (he's sat next to me), `UserFileRW.truncate()` does not delete the previous contents of the file and also there is an extra line between each line in the saved file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html), you could do this:

```
import fileinput
with fileinput.input(files=["test.txt"], inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if fileinput.lineno() == lev+1:     # line numbers start at 1, not 0
            UserLevelScore = int(line[2:5]) # assuming LevelScore is an int
            if LevelScore > UserLevelScore:
                line = "{}{:0>3}".format(line[:2], LevelScore)
                # right-justify LevelScore with leading zeroes
        print(line, end="") # Output is redirected to the current line of the file
```